# Image aspect ratio changing

Tags: graphics, formatting

so I'm pretty new to Latex and I'm trying to include a 716x540 image into my latex file like this:

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{image.jpg}
\caption{imagecaption}
\end{figure}
```

But after I convert the .tex to a .pdf via pandoc, the aspect ratio of the image has changed, as in the image is streched weirdly. Here's an image: [image: screenshot]
on the right you can see the original image and on the left is my pdf.

Why is this happening?

Edit: live demo: https://www.sharelatex.com/read/tnhkpdcbxyzq

Comment: Why pandoc and not pdflatex or something from latex family? If you are open to use pdflatex (you can do it on-line too : see sharelatex.com or overleaf.com) we can give it a try with o bigger compilable part of your code (see MWE : https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/120578 ) Also may be the option `keepaspectratio` in your includegraphisc command can solve your problem (even with pandoc-> but I haven't used it and I don't know enough) `\includegraphics[keepaspectratio]{image.jpg}`

Comment: @koleygr thanks for replying, I added a live link

Comment: @PhilippHemmelmayr: The link doesn't provide access to the document.

Comment: Philipp, you have to share the project from the menu of sharelatex to give as the right to read your code... Otherwise the link is not accessible from anyone but you (even if the name of the site doesn't make it clear :P )

Comment: updated the link, sorry

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was the problematic format of the specific image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in your project, if you replace the image you are using there with the other image it works fine... The problem is the image and has nothing to do with latex and friends.

I tried to open it with inkscape and it was like latex output.

Then tried with other programs and seemed to be ok... but wasn't.

Solution: I used shotwell and saved with the below settings :

[image]

The saved image was ok but I suggest to learn some tikz and create such images inside latex.

Comment: ah, thank you very much. I thought the image was ok because it showed up ok on my image viewer.

Comment: Welcome... hope that you already downloaded it because I will remove it from here...